# Let $H_{[a,b]}=\{f\in{L^2{(R)}}:support~~f \subset{[a,b]}\}$.Show that $H_{[a,b]}$ is a closed subspace of $L^2{(R)}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

My proof:$~~$We only need to show that $H_{[a,b]}$ is closed,i.e.,complete.Assume that $f_n$ is an any cauchy sequence in  $H_{[a,b]}$ and $lim_{n\to{+\infty}}f_n=f$.We show that $f\in{ H_{[a,b]}}$.

\begin{align*}
||f_n-f||_{L^2}^2=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f_n-f|^2dx
&= \int_{a}^{b}|f_n-f|^2dx+\int_{x<a~or~x>b}|f_n-f|^2dx    \\
&=\int_{a}^{b}|f_n-f|^2dx+\int_{x<a~or~x>b}|f|^2dx 
\end{align*}

Since $lim_{n\to{+\infty}}f_n=f$, then for any $\epsilon>0$,there is some $N>0$ so that $||f_n-f||_{L^2}^2<\epsilon$ holds for any $n>N$.

We immediately get that $$\int_{x<a~or~x>b}|f|^2dx<\epsilon$$ for any $\epsilon>0$.Thus $f=0~~a.e~~x>b~or~x<a$.Hence  $supp~~f\subset{[a,b]}~~almost$.

Is my proof correct?In my proof,I only show that $f=0~~a.e~~x>b~or~x<a$ and I can't get that $supp~~f\subset{[a,b]}$ exactly.Moreover,in functional space,how to identify whether  we should consider the definitions under the meaning of "almost everywhere" or "exactly"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L^2$ norm cannot tell the difference between almost everywhere and exactly, so your proof is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much,I always considered the difference between a.e and exactly before.